# Meaning of Extension option in Factor

Tags: functions, polynomials, algebraic-manipulation, factorization

I would like to ask about the [`Extension`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Extension.html) option in [`Factor`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Factor.html) function.

In the [reference](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Extension.html), there is the following example. Factor a polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$:

```
Factor[x^2 - 2, Extension -> Sqrt[2]]
(* -(Sqrt[2] - x) (Sqrt[2] + x) *)
```

In this example, each polynomial has coefficients that are rational combinations of the algebraic number $\sqrt{2}$. As it is stated in the [reference](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Factor.html).

Now, consider the polynomial $x^2 + \sqrt{2}\,x - 1$.
It has the roots $-\tfrac12(\sqrt{2} \pm \sqrt{6})$. Let's factor it over $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{6}]$:

```
Factor[x^2 + Sqrt[2]*x - 1, Extension -> Sqrt[6]]
(* -(1/4) (-Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[6] - 2 x) (Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[6] + 2 x) *)
```

But here, the constant term $\sqrt{2}$ is not a rational combination of $\sqrt{6}$. It seems it has been factored over $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2},\sqrt{6}]$.

> How exactly does the `Extension` option work?

Comment: But $\sqrt2$ is in the domain of coefficient of your original polynomial which is $\mathbb{Q[\sqrt2]}$. Coefficients are not rational numbers.

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci Yes, this is correct. But the reference mentions that `Extension` extends the rationals with a list of elements.

Comment: The documentation is a bit loose on the matter of what is the field being extended. It is the rationals plus algebraic numbers appearing in the input. Offhand I'm not sure if it also includes algebraic conjugates of those when they give a nontrivial further extension.